# URL redirect middleware in Microsoft.AspNetCore.Rewrite doesn't redirect

Tags: regex, asp.net-core, redirect

I am attempting to redirect one URL to another in .NET Core. The originating URL is

http://localhost:3000/en/ad/test/1758

and below you see the Configure() method of my Startup.cs. For some reason, this rule is never hit as far as I can see. If I change the regex to `^(.*)$` it will, of course, hit every time, but with the regex you see below it just doesn't work.

Why?

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, IApplicationLifetime applicationLifetime, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    app.UseRewriter(new RewriteOptions().AddRedirect(@"^en/ad/.*/(\d+)$", this.Configuration["Api:PublicUrl"] + "/en/ad/$1"));

    applicationLifetime.ApplicationStopping.Register(OnShutdown);

    loggerFactory.AddConsole();

    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }

    // Serve wwwroot as root
    app.UseFileServer();

    // Serve /node_modules as a separate root (for packages that use other npm modules client side)
    app.UseFileServer(new FileServerOptions()
    {
        // Set root of file server (remember not wwwroot!)
        FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(Path.Combine(env.ContentRootPath, "node_modules")),
        // Only react to requests that match this path
        RequestPath = "/node_modules"
    });
}
```

Comment: Would you like to redirect `http://localhost:3000/en/ad/test/1758` to `http://somesite.com/en/ad/1758`?

Comment: @Win Yes, and as it turns out I had a web.config with some rules that were intercepting this rule. That's why it didn't work. Since that I've written my own implementations of IRule to get the expected behaviour. I'll post an answer later today :)

Comment: I tested `@"^en/ad/.*/(\d+)$"`, and it worked as expected. I glad that you figure out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out I had an intercepting web.config rule, so the moral of the story is to fully port your web.config to .NET Core rules and not just partially :) Be thorough!